# Sort passed in Pageable to Spring controller appends direction to property name, causing a SQL error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-webclient

I need to call a pageable endpoint in my Spring Boot app from another Spring Boot app. I'm trying to pass the pageable options through from the first app to the second, but I'm having an issue where the property name comes in as `firstName: ASC`. When the direction is appended to that, it becomes `firstName: ASC: ASC` which causes the JPA query to throw an exception.

What's the proper way to pass the pageable options from my first endpoint to my second?

**Calling app**

```java
@GetMapping("/v1/users")
    public Flux<User> getUsersByAccount(@RequestParam Long accountId,
                                        @PageableDefault(size = 10, sort = "firstName") Pageable pageable) {
        return userService.getUsersByAccount(accountId, pageable);
}
```

```
public Flux<User> getUsersByAccount(Long accountId, Pageable pageable) {
    int page = pageable.getPageNumber();
    int size = pageable.getPageSize();
    Sort sort = pageable.getSort();

    return webClient.backendService()
        .get().uri(builder -> builder
            .path("/rest/users")
            .queryParam("accountId", accountId)
            .queryParam("page", page)
            .queryParam("size", size)
            .queryParam("sort", sort)
            .build())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(ContactInfo.class);
}
```

I am splitting the Pageable out into its components because I wasn't sure how to pass the whole object at once since it's not a named parameter in the second app. Note that at this point, the sort looks fine and appears as it should with `firstName` and `ASC` as separate values for property name and direction, respectively.

**Called app**

```java
@GetMapping("/rest/users")
    public List<User> getUsersByAccount(@RequestParam Long accountId, Pageable pageable) {
        return userService.getUsersByAccount(accountId, pageable);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste `User` class?

Comment: You cannot pass the `Sort` like that. You have to deconstruct it and pass the individual arguments.

Comment: @M.Deinum What am I to do after deconstructing it; just build a String array? Looking at the deconstructed Pageable in Swagger, it takes in `page`, `size`, and `sort`: https://i.imgur.com/5yn1F7M.png

Comment: Yes it takes a sort but you cannot simply put in a `Sort` as what happens is it will call `toString` which isn't a proper representation. What you should send is `sort=firstname_asc,lastname_desc` or whatever the fields are you are using.

Comment: Ah, okay. I tried deconstructing as a string like `["firstName, ASC"]` but apparently it's space-sensitive even within array elements so was creating an additional property `ASC`. Sending as `["firstName,ASC"]` worked though. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M. Deinum mentioned, `Sort`'s `toString()` doesn't produce a representation that can be directly serialized back into a `Sort` object, (and there is no such method on the object to do that).

You can convert it to the proper form like this:

```
List<String> sorts = new ArrayList<>();
sort.forEach(order -> sorts.add(String.join(",", order.getProperty(), order.getDirection().toString())));
builder.queryParam("sort", sorts.toArray());
```

This produces the correct representation of `["propertyName,direction"]`.

Comment: You want `order.getDirection().name()` instead of `order.getDirection().toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Controller we can capture HttpServletRequest as follows

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<PriceBook>> getAll(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(priceBookService.findAll(servletRequest), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

use queryString as follows to pass all request parameters to the backend service

```
public PageableResponse<PriceBook> getPbAllWithFilter(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

    return webClient.get().uri(pbUrl.concat("?").concat(servletRequest.getQueryString()))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header(CORRELATION_ID, MDC.get(CORRELATION_ID_MDC))
                    .exchange()
                    .flatMap(this::getSubscriptionAll)
                    .block();

}
```